# Enabling Logs for AWS WAF WebAcl does not work in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

My goal is to enable logging for a regional WebAcl via AWS CDK. This [seems to be possible](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-loggingconfiguration.html) over Cloud Formation and there are the appropriate constructs in CDK. But when using the following code to create a Log Group and linking it in a [LoggingConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_wafv2.CfnLoggingConfiguration.html) ...

```
  const webAclLogGroup = new LogGroup(scope, "awsWafLogs", {
    logGroupName: `aws-waf-logs`
  });

  // Create logging configuration with log group as destination
  new CfnLoggingConfiguration(scope, "webAclLoggingConfiguration", {
    logDestinationConfigs: webAclLogGroup.logGroupArn, // Arn of LogGroup
    resourceArn: aclArn // Arn of Acl
  });
```

... I get an exception during `cdk deploy`, stating that the string in the LogdestinationConfig is not a correct Arn (some parts of the Arn in the log messages have been removed):

```
Resource handler returned message: "Error reason: The ARN isn't valid. A valid ARN begins with arn: and includes other information separated by colons or slashes., field: LOG_DESTINATION, parameter: arn:aws:logs:xxx:xxx:xxx-awswaflogsF99ED1BA-PAeH9Lt2Y3fi:* (Service: Wafv2, Status Code: 400, Request ID: xxx, Extended Request ID: null)"
```

I cannot see an error in the generated Cloud Formation code after `cdk synth`:

```
"webAclLoggingConfiguration": {
  "id": "webAclLoggingConfiguration",
  "path": "xxx/xxx/webAclLoggingConfiguration",
  "attributes": {
    "aws:cdk:cloudformation:type": "AWS::WAFv2::LoggingConfiguration",
    "aws:cdk:cloudformation:props": {
      "logDestinationConfigs": [
        {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            {
              "Ref": "awsWafLogs58D3FD01"
            },
            "Arn"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "resourceArn": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "webACL",
          "Arn"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "constructInfo": {
    "fqn": "aws-cdk-lib.aws_wafv2.CfnLoggingConfiguration",
    "version": "2.37.1"
  }
},
```

I'm using Cdk with Typescript and the Cdk version is currently set to `2.37.1` but it also did not work with `2.16.0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WAF has particular requirements to the naming and format of Logging Destination configs as [described](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/logging-cw-logs.html#logging-cw-logs-naming) and [shown](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/wafv2/put-logging-configuration.html#examples) in their docs.

Specifically, the ARN of the Log Group cannot end in `:*` which unfortunately is the [return value for a Log Group ARN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-logs-loggroup.html#aws-resource-logs-loggroup-return-values) in Cloudformation.

A workaround would be to construct the required ARN format manually like this, which will omit the `:*` suffix. Also note that `logDestinationConfigs` takes a List of Strings, though only with exactly 1 element in it.

```
  const webAclLogGroup = new LogGroup(scope, "awsWafLogs", {
    logGroupName: `aws-waf-logs`
  });

  // Create logging configuration with log group as destination
  new CfnLoggingConfiguration(scope, "webAclLoggingConfiguration", {
    logDestinationConfigs: [
      // Construct the different ARN format from the logGroupName
      Stack.of(this).formatArn({
        arnFormat: ArnFormat.COLON_RESOURCE_NAME,
        service: "logs",
        resource: "log-group",
        resourceName: webAclLogGroup.logGroupName,
      })
    ],
    resourceArn: aclArn // Arn of Acl
  });
```

PS: I work for AWS on the CDK team.

Comment: Your solution worked! Do you know which IAM permissions are needed to execute this function? I gave reduced permissions for the cdk bootstrap and it failed in my normal setup. The error message, however does not display which permissions are required. When changing my policy to permit all (*) it works.

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't know which permissions you need. I usually check this page to get an idea about required permissions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_awswafv2.html
Look for the `PutLoggingConfiguration` entry in the table.